# MySQL: get distinct, different, values between two queries

Tags: mysql

I have a query with a sub-query. Both return a list of users IDs. in inner query gives me all customers who used cash in a particular location within a given time frame.

The second, selects all user ids from the first that ordered after a specific date and did not use cash as a form of payment.

```
select distinct c.user_id
from (
    select distinct o.user_id
    from `order` as o
    inner join payments as p on p.id = o.id
    where o.orderplaced_ts > "2016-01-01 00:00:00"
    and o.store_id = "12"
    and p.payment_method = "Cash"
) as c
inner join `order` as o on c.user_id = o.user_id
inner join `payments` as p on o.id = p.id
where o.orderplaced_ts > "2016-03-13 00:00:00"
and o.store_id = "12"
and p.payment_method != "Cash"
```

How do I get the cross between the users that did no order since `2016-03-13`.

For reference:

```
select distinct o.user_id
from `order` as o
inner join payments as p on p.id = o.id
where o.orderplaced_ts > "2016-01-01 00:00:00"
and o.store_id = "12"
and p.payment_method = "Cash"
```

Returns 236 Unique IDs - call this set A

Both queries combines return 160 unique ID - call this set B

Which IDs are in Set A and are `not` in set B

Comment: change last 2 `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` and add `p.id IS NULL` condition to ending `WHERE` clause

Comment: @alex that returns 0 rows, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer to get some sqlfiddle from your side.

But since I have not, here is my attempt:

```
select distinct c.user_id
from (
    select distinct o.user_id
    from `order` as o
    inner join payments as p on p.id = o.id
    where o.orderplaced_ts > "2016-01-01 00:00:00"
    and o.store_id = "12"
    and p.payment_method = "Cash"
) as c
LEFT JOIN `order` as o 
ON c.user_id = o.user_id
   AND o.orderplaced_ts > "2016-03-13 00:00:00"
   AND o.store_id = "12"
LEFT JOIN `payments` as p 
ON o.id = p.id
   AND p.payment_method != "Cash"
WHERE p.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks. At first, I had a brain fart and followed your directions explicitly. I realized after that I had to remove the bottom conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Use a not in clause between the two query

```
select distinct o.user_id
from `order` as o
inner join payments as p on p.id = o.id
where o.orderplaced_ts > "2016-01-01 00:00:00"
and o.store_id = "12"
and p.payment_method = "Cash"
and o.user_id not in (

    select distinct c.user_id
    from (
        select distinct o.user_id
        from `order` as o
     inner join payments as p on p.id = o.id
        where o.orderplaced_ts > "2016-01-01 00:00:00"
        and o.store_id = "12"
        and p.payment_method = "Cash"
    ) as c
    inner join `order` as o on c.user_id = o.user_id
    inner join `payments` as p on o.id = p.id
    where o.orderplaced_ts > "2016-03-13 00:00:00"
    and o.store_id = "12"

)
```